How to feed electrical wire from switched outdoor sconce to junction box?
I'm in Pennsylvania (US).
We recently had a patio installed and I chose to do the electrical myself. I've done tons and tons of residential electrical, including weatherproof outdoor receptacles, but those were wired through the back attached to the home.
I didn't expect the patio company to install a junction box, it's one I am having trouble figuring out how to work with.
The closest I've been able to find online is this one,
though mine appears to be a 1 gang.
There doesn't seem to be room to access the top hub without cutting the siding, so my plan was to cap the top and drill a hole on the left side, and add a cable gland or something to feed the 14/2 coming from the wall light (the loose wire in the pictures, powered by a switch in the house), and connect that to the two wires going through the conduit coming into the bottom of the box that is feeding the post lights.
None of the PVC caps I've found at Home Depot or Lowes fit the top, and I'm unsure what the best connection from the side would be. I've learned that I can connect to the top via sch 40 conduit, but I'd prefer to not notch the siding, and am not sure how to get the wire from the wall light into the conduit in a watertight fashion.
The top opening is 1", and I'm having trouble finding reducer bushings if I were to need to go this route.
I'm stumped, and could really use some direction/links to products that will help me actually light our new patio. I'm very comfortable with the electrical portion of this job, just unsure how to proceed with the provided junction box.
Link to pictures: https://imgur.com/a/VhwadNo
Additional picture showing why I would prefer to feed the wire from the side. The feed wire is coming from the left, under the siding.
https://imgur.com/a/qXOCDsI

Why not replace it with a nice metal box with knockouts that you use as needed?

Is that cable coming from the left, under the siding, rated for outdoor/wet use? If you're not sure, see if you can find any codes printed on the cable. While indoor non-metallic cable (a.k.a. Romex based on a common brand) is generally accepted for a run through a wall into the back of a box, that doesn't work for an actual outside run such as this one.

Yes, it is UF-B https://imgur.com/a/93gPX32

Take the screws out that anchor the box and shim the box out the 1/4 inch or so with stainless steel washers.  Replace the screws with slightly longer ones. Preferably stainless also. (no rusting)
Then you can get conduit in the top hub and feed your wires.

I would prefer to enter from the side and cap the top to avoid continuing to go up. The feed wire is coming from the left, under the siding. I've added an additional picture to the post

It's you box and house, but you should not drill into a weather rated box.  If it was put in against your wishes and is causing that much of a problem, remove the box and install what you want.  Just be sure it is all rated for outdoor use and done to code, or your insurance company can refuse a claim if there is an issue.

Agree with @RMDman  Driling holes in weatherproof boxes is a NO NO.  I was required to replace one after correctly adding a circuit because prior workers drilled a hole in the back of the box.

Electrician here:
While UF cable is rated for direct burial, and it's also fine inside a structure, it's not supposed to be run on the outside of a structure. (free-air)
The cleanest ways I can think of to salvage this and ensure code compliance would be:

A. Make a hole in the back of the box, and attempt to bring the wire through the wall and into the box. (use a conduit fitting and/or some good sealant to keep that wall penetration weather-tight)
B. Make a hole in the left side and run conduit over and down for the cable.
C. Cut the conduit coming up to the box and redo it with some 90s to turn the box horizontal and use the "top" (now left side) fitting to run conduit over and down to your cable. (would look like a wide, upside down U when finished)

Also, as manassehkatz-moving-2-codidact suggested, a nice weatherproof metal box (preferably 2-gang) with threaded plugs on all four sides and/or back would be superior to drilling out the one you already have. It'll cost you a new box, 2-3 new fittings, and some extra work, but may work out better in the long run.

...do you have a citation for UF not being permitted for being on a structure/otherwise exposed, or are you saying that due to physical damage issues? (I ask because UF on a messenger is permitted by the NEC for overhead wiring, so clearly the fact that it's exposed isn't the sole issue here)

I'm going to do a new box, the wiring from the switched light says sunlight resistant and is behind siding (usually). Would you suggest replacing the wire with conduit for the whole run, or just the exposed part from under the siding to the box?

I'm thinking the whole thing was amateurish to begin with. I'll post pictures tomorrow, but the wire comes out of the light, behind an inside corner trim of the vinyl siding, then under the siding as seen in the pictures. There's no reasonable way to round the corner inside the home without quite a bit of drywall work, so I'm thinking I may need conduit from the light to the new junction box. Not sure if uf-b can be behind the siding the way it is
